# Connected App permission

Tags: security, connected-apps

I want to control which of my users can allow a connected app.
Can I as an admin prevent users from "Allowing" a connected app?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that setting the permission of the app to "Admin approved Users are Preauthorized" will block those users not specifically authorized to use the app by the admin:

[image]